# CSS HTML textarea in divs within divs max height minus header

Tags: css, html

here is the HTML code i am using:

```
<div id="header">123</div>
<div id="editorcontent">
    <div id="ta_a"><textarea style="resize: none;"><? echo $t1; ?></textarea></div>
    <div id="ta_c"><textarea style="resize: none;"><? echo $t2; ?></textarea></div>
    <div id="centerinfo">CONTENT 1</div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="centerinfo">CONTENT 2</div>
    <div id="ta_b"><textarea style="resize: none;"><? echo $u1; ?></textarea></div>
    <div id="ta_d"><textarea style="resize: none;"><? echo $u2; ?></textarea></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#editorcontent {
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#ta_a {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#ta_c {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}

#ta_b {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#ta_d {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}
#centerinfo {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 19.6%;
  height: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#clear {
  clear:both;
  min-height: 10px;
}
#header {
  height: 44px;
  background: #D00000;
}
```

The problem is that the 2 times 50% from the textareas are not not looking at the header causing the page always to be too large in height...

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/5SD2U/

Comment: `2 times 50% from the textareas are not not looking at the header causing the page always to be too large in height` your question isn't clear. What are you trying to achieve? The `#ta__` height isn't dependant on header, it is dependent on their container's height which isn't set in your CSS

Comment: the #editorcontent height where all of the textareas are in is `height: auto;`

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when loading my page, the div #editorcontent takes 100% of the pages height, but adds this to the height of the header, which i do not want. so what i would like is something like height 100% - 44px (header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you need either javascript/jQuery or a CSS hack. I made a fiddle with the CSS hack. It involves setting your #editorcontent div to 100%, adding a header_placeholder div, and setting the header's position to absolute. Also keep in mind that you will always have to manually set the height of the header and the placeholder to the same number.

Also you have to set the body and html to padding: 0, margin: 0, width: 100%, and height: 100%, else this probably won't work in all browsers.

Here is the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5SD2U/1/

And here is the code for reference:
The HTML:

```
<div id="header">123</div>
<div id="editorcontent">
    <div id="header_placeholder"></div>
    <div id="ta_a"><textarea style="resize: none;">1</textarea></div>
    <div id="ta_c"><textarea style="resize: none;">2</textarea></div>
    <div id="centerinfo">CONTENT 1</div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="centerinfo">CONTENT 2</div>
    <div id="ta_b"><textarea style="resize: none;">3</textarea></div>
    <div id="ta_d"><textarea style="resize: none;">4</textarea></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#editorcontent {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#header_placeholder {
    height: 44px; /* height of the header */
}
#ta_a {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#ta_c {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}

#ta_b {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#ta_d {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}
#centerinfo {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 19.6%;
  height: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#clear {
  clear:both;
  min-height: 10px;
}
#header {
  height: 44px;
  background: #D00000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
```